# media query css3 window aspect ratio

Tags: css

Is there any way to get the window aspect ratio in a css media query? I have found the `device-aspect-ratio`, and `device-pixel-ratio`, but it seems that it is all possible to get several breakpoints based on pixel size and number of pixels and also device width. Is it not simpler to make website relative to the browser window because the browser window spans over the whole device on mobile phones (for now) but on PC you can resize your window to your wishes?

So is there any workaround or do I need to do some server/client side programming?

Thank you enigma. English is not my first language.

Comment: use javascript. Is that a possible approach? I know various javascript that can supply window size/dimensions but really, on mobile devices, window size == screen size anyway.

Comment: well ... javascript is possible but it is buggy with output and order. i was thinking that it could be easier that server get the information from client and than just implement correct value of the style when sending the page. Like this server will send the full page without parameters or with default parameter and than the client will manage the page on its preferences. AJAX could be possible, but i need to learn it well enough.